# Storing getting and storing IP address

Tags: php, mysql, ip

I currently have a function that stores a query that has been entered into a form. I am trying to save the IP address of the user that submits the form along with the input.

Currently this is the function:

```
 function userIP(){
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];     
    if($ip){
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];

        $ipis = ip2long($ip);
        }
        return $ip;
    }
    return false;
}

 public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
     if( isset( $data['text'] ) ) $this->text = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['text'] ) );
     if( isset( $data['ipis'] ) ) $this->ipis = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['ipis'] ) );
 }

 public function storeFormValues( $params ) {
    $this->__construct( $params ); 
 }


     public function store() {
    $correct = false;
        try {
            $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl(content, ip) VALUES(:text, :ipis)";

            $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindValue( "text", $this->text, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( "ipis", $this->ipis, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();
            return "Added";
        }catch( PDOException $e ) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
 }
```

}

However it currently only stores the "text" that was input and just adds NULL to the database for IP.
The MYSQL for the IP row is set up as an unsigned INT 11.
Any ideas on fixing the issue?

Comment: May be you need to change data type to varchar to store IP address

Comment: Shouldn't need to because I am using ip2long

Comment: Ip2long may return negative values. Guess what needs to be done as 1st measure?

Comment: What do you use ip for? Do you realize `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` can be faked **easily**?

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your function returning the long value. You have placed the return statement in the elseif condition. Also, you are returning the actual `$ip` value as is.

```
function userIP(){
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];   
if($ip){
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    $ipis = ip2long($ip);
    return $ipis;
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string to store the IP in the database

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the issue, when trying to echo out the Ip it doesn't even show it. So as far as I can see it is not even grabbing the IP to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option:

```
function userIP(){
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];     
  if( !$ip )
    return false;
  if( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ) )
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
  if( !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) )
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  return sprintf( '%u' , ip2long( $ip ) );
}
```

After reading the [PHP Manual on `ip2long()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php#refsect1-function.ip2long-notes) I found something interesting about how it handles large integers on some systems.